# Different versions of Mercer's theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory, compact-operators

I am reviewing materials on [reproducing kernel Hilbert space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reproducing_kernel_Hilbert_space) (RKHS) and I've found various versions of Mercer's theorem:

1. About the positive-definiteness conditions.

   In the Wikipedia pages on RKHS above or on the [theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercer%27s_theorem) itself, the condition is

   $$\sum_{i,j =1}^n c_i c_j K(x_i, x_j) \ge  0 , \forall  n \in \mathbb{N},\ x_1, \dots, x_n \in X,\ \mbox{and}\ c_1, \dots, c_n \in \mathbb{R},$$

   while in some other materials (for example [this](http://alex.smola.org/teaching/exponential101/Lecture05.pdf), page 16), the condition becomes an integral:

   [image]

   In [T. Hofmann *et. al*](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aos/1211819561) there is a short comment on this:

   [image]

   So according to the text they are different. Thus **my first question** is, what is the connection between these two conditions?
2. About the function space of $K$.

   Again in the Wikipedia pages on [Mercer's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercer%27s_theorem), it mentions that $K$ is a [Hilbert–Schmidt integral operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93Schmidt_integral_operator), which is like saying $K\in\mathcal{L}^2(\mathcal{X}^2)$ if I understand correctly. But in the attached slide above, it requires $K\in\mathcal{L}^\infty(\mathcal{X}^2)$, and gives $(\lambda_j)\in\ell_1$. This conclusion seems not covered by the [spectral theory of compact and self-adjoint operators on Hilbert space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_operator_on_Hilbert_space#Spectral_theorem), which only states a weaker result $\lambda_j\to 0$. It looks to me that $K\in\mathcal{L}^\infty(\mathcal{X}^2)$ helps give $(\lambda_j)\in\ell_1$. So **my second question** is, what is the general requirement of the function space for $K$, and how will the choice of spaces affect the properties of $(\lambda_j)$?

Comment: the wikipedia positiveness condition is correct for piecewise continuous $k$, not when it is a distribution (for example a matrix !), so I prefer the second for all test function $f$

Comment: this may help you further understanding https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2133637/inequality-in-mercers-theorem-proof/2133829#2133829

Comment: If the comments answered your question, you could briefly summarise them in an answer so this question doesn't remain "not answered".